# R crop raster using polygon keeping cells along the border

Tags: r, polygon, crop, mask, raster

I'm trying to crop [this raster](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23404805/stackoverflow/x.nc) over Italy but the output seems to miss some of the cells along the border. See areas highlighted in red in the picture below:
[image]

How can I keep all the cells that cross the borders?

Below is my script:

```
library(raster)

# Load data
x <- raster("x.nc")
IT <- getData(name = "GADM", country = "Italy", level = 0)

# Mask and crop
x_masked <- mask(x, IT)
x_masked_cropped <- crop(x_masked, IT)

# Plot
plot(x_masked_cropped)
plot(IT, add = T)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could identify all raster cells intersecting Italy and set the remaining, i.e. non-intersecting pixels to NA. Make sure to retrieve cells with their respective weights via `cellFromPolygon(..., weights = TRUE)` - otherwise, only cells that have their center inside Italy will be returned (see also `?raster::extract`).

```
## identify cells covering italy and set all remaining pixels to NA
cls <- cellFromPolygon(x, IT, weights = TRUE)[[1]][, "cell"]
x[][-cls] <- NA

plot(trim(x))
plot(IT, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it. We create a binary mask raster with `gdalUtils::gdal_rasterize`, using `at=TRUE` to ensure that the value 1 is burnt into all cells touched by the Italy polygon. `gdal_rasterize` refers to files on disk, so write `IT` out to an OGR-supported file first.

```
library(gdalUtils)
library(rgdal)
x_crop <- crop(x, IT)
writeOGR(IT, tempdir(), f <- basename(tempfile()), 'ESRI Shapefile')
gdal_rasterize(sprintf('%s/%s.shp', tempdir(), f), 
               f2 <- tempfile(fileext='.tif'), at=T,
               tr=res(x_crop), te=c(bbox(x_crop)), burn=1, 
               init=0, a_nodata=0, ot='Byte')

plot(x_crop*raster(f2)) # multiply the raster by 1 or NA
plot(IT, add=TRUE)
```

[image]